# Nuxt & Vue - Element UI Persisting active menu item on browser back button event

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js, element-ui

My problem is that for a given clicked menu item, there is a 'selected' state that simply darkens the item for user feedback. The issue is that the active item is being reset when the browser back button is pressed while the route still changes correctly. I put together a quick functional demo of what is happening here: https://codepen.io/soodohcool/pen/xxbambE

```
/* the codepen is for illustrating the behavior of my issue */
```

click on the menu items a few times then press the "simulate back" button to see what happens. Note the page title changes properly but the active state goes away on the menu item.

I am using Nuxt/Vue with Element UI in my actual project. I was thinking using middleware on the router would be appropriate here to just set the 'default-active' prop on the menu when the route changes, but I am new to Nuxt and wanted to get some pro input before I slapped something together that may be bad practice.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If anything needs clarification please let me know, it is my first time here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your nuxt.config.js file add the following:

```
router: {
    linkExactActiveClass: 'active'
}
```

nuxt doesn't use an active class by default for active links.

Also you will need to use the `<nuxt-link>` component for the active class to be bound to the active page link
https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-link/

Comment: Thank you for your response....Unfortunately, I am using Element UI for the Nav so I am afraid this won't quite cut it. More specifically it seems to be an issue with Element itself rather than Nuxt.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was able to solve it with a little experimentation and it was remarkably simple.

1. Set the **default-active** prop to **$route.path**
2. Set the **index** of the item to it's respective path

That is what worked for me, hopefully it helps someone in the future